# Irrational root of polynomial problem (Putnam 1976/A4)

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, irrational-numbers

Let $p(x) ≡ x^3 + ax^2 + bx - 1$, and $q(x) ≡ x^3 + cx^2 + dx + 1$ be polynomials with integer coefficients. Let $α$ be a root of $p(x) = 0$. $p(x)$ is irreducible over the rationals. $α + 1$ is a root of $q(x) = 0$. Find an expression for another root of p(x) = 0 in terms of $α$, but not involving $a$, $b$, $c$, or $d$.

My question is about the following solution:

Let the roots of $p(x)$ be $α$, $β$, $γ$. The polynomial $q(x+1)$ has $α$ as one of its roots. Suppose it is different from $p(x)$. Then by subtracting we get either a quadratic or a linear equation which also has $α$ as a root. It cannot be a linear equation, because then $α$ would be rational and hence $p(x)$ would not be irreducible over the rationals. If it was quadratic, then by multiplying it by a suitable rational factor $rx + s$ and subtracting from $p(x)$ we would get a linear factor $ux + v$ which also had $α$ as a root. If this factor is zero, then we have reduced $p(x)$ over the rationals (as ($rx + s$) times the quadratic). If not, then $α$ is a root of $ux + v$ and hence rational, so that $p(x)$ is still reducible. So we must have that $p(x)$ and $q(x+1)$ are identical.

Rest can be found here: https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol764.html

Specifically, I'm ok up to the stage of "subtracting from $p(x)$ we would get a linear factor $ux + v$ which also had $α$ as a root..."

Why is a linear factor guaranteed? Perhaps I'm failing to read something into the previous line about the *suitable* rational factor that would make this happen?

Also, supposing we do get this linear factor, what does it then mean for it to be zero?

Comment: Is it $dx$ instead of $d^x$ that you meant?

Comment: Hint: consider the quotient and remainder one gets when doing polynomial long division to divide $p(x)$ by the hypothetical quadratic difference.

Comment: q(x) can't be a polynomial with $d^x$, according to the definition of polynomial.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to write dx. I think I’ve figured it out now. The “suitable” rational factor can be chosen to give a cubic with the same leading and second coefficients as p(x), so this guarantees the linear factor after subtraction, and since all coefficients are rational, this implies the linear factor has a rational root (or that the whole cubic is identical to p(x) in which case the linear factor is “zero”.) Does this sound right?

Comment: Since $\alpha$ is a root of $q(x+1)$ and $p(x) $ is minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ it follows that $p(x) \mid q(x+1)$. Both these are monic and of same degree hence $p(x) =q(x+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\alpha^3+a\alpha^2+b\alpha-1=0$$ $$(\alpha+1)^3+c(\alpha+1)^2+d(\alpha+1)+1=0$$ from which
$$a\alpha^2+b\alpha-1=3\alpha^2+3\alpha+1+c(\alpha+1)^2+d(\alpha+1)+1$$  Because $\alpha$ is an irrational of degree $3$, the coefficients of the powers of $\alpha$ in this last equation should be zero so

$c=a-3,d=a,b=3(a-1)$ then
$$p(x)=x^3+ax^2+3(a-1)x-1$$ From $p(\alpha)=0$ we have $$\boxed{a=\frac{3\alpha+1-\alpha^3}{\alpha^2+3\alpha}\Rightarrow b=\frac{-3(\alpha^3+\alpha^2-1)}{\alpha^2+3\alpha}}$$
Now by Vieta we have the system for the other two roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$
$$\alpha+\alpha_1+\alpha_2=-a$$ $$\alpha\alpha_1\alpha_2=-(-1)=1$$
Which are solutions of the equation $$X^2+(a+\alpha)X+\frac{1}{\alpha}=0$$ We are done.